# Why does Dropbox add *com.dropbox.attributes files?

Tags: macos, dropbox

I'm a Mac user who shares various files in Dropbox with my Windows-using colleagues.  Regularly, I find lots *com.dropbox.attributes files in my shared folders.  This appears to create one for each file and folder - considering there's a couple of hundred files in here, it makes for a messy folder than I can't easily search.

Does anyone have a good way of hiding these files?

Comment: Those aren't supposed to be _files_, but [extended attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#OS_X) attached to your actual files. If they show up like this, perhaps Dropbox is buggy or you're using an unusual filesystem?

Comment: NTFS support streams: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx -- Your MAC file system likely does not support NTFS streams.

Answer (score 0):

SetFile is your friend.  This changes the attributes of the file for my Mac, but doesn't affect anything for the Windows machines.

In a terminal window, go to the folder you want to hide things (I've only done it in the folder I'm having problems and type the following

```
SetFile -a V *\:com.dropbox.attributes && SetFile -a V **/*\:com.dropbox.attributes
```

There's undoubtedly a way to write this in one command, but this works enough for my needs

Comment: Can you explain what `SetFile -a V …` does?  Can you explain why you need the `\:`?  What would happen if you typed just `*:com.dropbox…`?  Can you explain why you need the `**`?  What would happen if you typed just `*/*:com.dropbox…`?  Can you combine arguments into a single command; e.g., `SetFile -a V *\:co… **/*\:co…`?

Answer (score 0):

(Linux, outside Dropbox folder):

I've had similar files show up after copying files from Windows (Dropbox) tp Linux (outside Dropbox, WSL).
Since the destination was outside Dropbox, I think there's no reason for those files to show up there (Dropbox bug?), so I just delete them via:

```
rm *.attrs
```

(My files end on *.attrs* not *.attributes*).
To list them before deleting: `ls *.attrs`

The difference to the answer using `SetFile -a V ...` is that I'm not trying to set them hidden/invisible, but just deleting.

Answer (score -1):

RiggerTheGeek's answer is very useful and valuable. However, since it allowed only two levels, and I wanted to go five levels deep, I extended it as follows:

```
SetFile -a V *\:com.dropbox.attributes &&
SetFile -a V **/*\:com.dropbox.attributes &&
SetFile -a V **/**/*\:com.dropbox.attributes &&
SetFile -a V **/**/**/*\:com.dropbox.attributes &&
SetFile -a V **/**/**/**/*\:com.dropbox.attributes &&
SetFile -a V **/**/**/**/**/*\:com.dropbox.attributes
```

Hopefully this presentation makes it clearer how to extend it even further.

Comment: Can you explain what `SetFile -a V …` does?  Can you explain why you need the `\:`?  What would happen if you typed just `*:com.dropbox…`?  Can you explain why you need the `**`?  What would happen if you typed just `*/*:com.dropbox…`?  Can you combine arguments into a single command;  e.g., `SetFile -a V *\:co… **/*\:co…`?